# QFT book that explains renormalization in detail via scalar field theory before going into fermions, etc.?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, renormalization, education

I am taking a QFT intro course and for some reason the professor decided to explain renormalization in more detail instead of going into particles with spin, QED, etc. first. They used only scalar theories for the examples ($\phi^3$ and $\phi^4$ mostly).

Sadly in most reference books (Schwartz, Peskin & Schröder...) renormalization is explained through examples with theories involving fermions, photons etc. So I am looking for a QFT book that explains renormalization topics through scalar theories.

Comment: It sounds like your professor is following Srednicki.

Comment: A book by Collins entitled Renormalization...

Comment: If you want a precise treatment then see https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5003

Answer (score 1):

Ryder's QFT book starts the first few sections on renormalization on the $\phi^4$ theory so this would be my recommendation.